# Regular expression to disallow special characters that are invalid in a Windows Folder name

Tags: regex, special-characters

I have a C# .Net MVC 3 web app.  I am needing to decorate a property with a RegEx data annotation that conforms to the rules for a windows folder name.  The invalid characters are: \, /, *, : , ? , “, <, >, |

I'm not a greate RegEx developer and I've tried a few RegEx's but they have all disallowed the - character which our app needs to allow.

I have tried:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(([_][a-zA-Z0-9])?[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*$

^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$

^( [a-zA-Z] )( ( [a-zA-Z_\-\s0-9\.\)\(] )( [^\\!@#$%^&/:*?<>""|]* ) )*$
```

Valid:

```
MyFilemane-!@#$%^&
```

Invalid:

```
MyFilename|
MyFileName\
```

Comment: @hwnd...good point.  I have edited the question.

Comment: Show some example data you are trying to match so we can see what you are wanting for a output result.

Comment: @hwnd...I'm wanting to match anything but the stated characters

Comment: So you want to match something like `\\server\dir` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a resolution at the following web address [RegEx for valid Windows Folder/File name](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=valid%20filename&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20)

The Regex resolution is:

```
^[^\\\./:\*\?\""<>\|]{1}[^\\/:\*\?\""<>\|]{0,254}$
```

Which also applies the 255 character limitation requirement.

The resolution applied in MVC3 C# .Net Code.  Title is a property of my C# class:

```
[Display(Name = "Title")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\\\./:\*\?\""<>\|]{1}[^\\/:\*\?\""<>\|]{0,254}$", 
    ErrorMessage = @"The following special characters are not allowed: \ / * :  ?  "" < > | ")]
public virtual string Title { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without using regular expressions by using the following:

- [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx)
- [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars.aspx)

See the documentation, they give full examples of implementing these methods.

To check your path or filenames:

```
var invalidPath = Path.GetInvalidPathChars(path)
var invalidFN   = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars(file)
```

I would implement the [StringBuilder Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) for doing this also.

If you are looking to do this using a regex, this should work for you.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+?[^\\\/:*?"<>|\n\r]+$
```

Comment: @hwnd...that's a good answer - thanks for that.  But the resolution I need uses the Data Annotations on a property of a class.  I can make the question more clear.  I did find an answer and will post it